# Invalidate first login session in case of concucrrent session in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

> It is clustered environment

In my currnet spring boot application I want to allow 5 concurrent session at a given time. When the user try to login 6th time then 6th session should be a valid session and it should invalidate the first session (i.e logout from the first session), so total number of active session will be 5.

Is it achievable by configuration in below code?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(5)
}
```

Comment: Is the application balanced on multiple machines using a loadbalancer?

Comment: Yes, It is clustered environment

Comment: This is essential! Please point that out in your question!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it is. As stated in this [blaeding-post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session). Did you already try it?

> To enable the scenario which allows multiple concurrent sessions for the same user the  `<session-management>` element should be used in the XML configuration:

```
<http ...>
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Or, via Java configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(2)
}
```

The code is also from this site.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Let me test it.

Comment: Attention, its clustered. Synchronization on server-level will not work across multiple instances.

Comment: I got this link (https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-session-for-concurrent-session-contro), it should be work fine in clustered environment. can someone confirm?

Comment: @PeterRader that information was added after I posted my answer - but thanks for downvoting.

Comment: @Rainer Your solution is very good, do not get me wrong. A downvote is not against you and the style of your answer is good and linked with official sources. Unfortunately the context of the question have changed and it 1. is not usefull in the changed context anymore. 2. leads others to invest time for solving the problem this way, even passing all test maybe. If I could, I would downvote the answer but upvote you.